# How to find the circle of curvature centre

Tags: calculus, circles, curvature

For the following question I am asked to

> find the radius for circle of curvature for the function:
> $-0.18e^{4.88x}$

I found the radius 1.681459915,
by using the formula: R =1/ρ
and this was correct *however*

when my answers for finding the centre is **incorrect** and I am unsure why.
It is close though.
I have attached a photo of my working out but I will also note it here.
I used the forumula:

```
(x+R(dy/dx), y+R)
```

and from that I got:
(-0.1902818505, 1.65590175)
[image]

the correct answers are:

> (x,y) = (-.0608106, -1.69409)

Any explanation as to how these correct answers were found and where I went wrong? am I using the wrong forumla? I have gotten 4 of the same questions wrong and I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

We have $f(x,y) = y + 0.48 e^{4.88 x} = 0$ and the normal to that function at the point $p=(-0.40,-0.48 e^{4.88 (-0.40)})$ is $\vec v = (0.8784e^{4.88(-0.40)},1)$ then the circle's center is located at

$$
(x_0,y_0)= p - R\frac{\vec v}{\|\vec v\|} = (-0.4,-0.0255582)-1.681459915(0.123765, 0.992312) = (-0.608106, -1.69409)
$$

In red $-\frac{\vec v}{\|\vec v\|}$ in blue $f(x,y)=0$ and in dotted black, the osculating circle: the black dot it's center $(x_0,y_0)$ and the selected point in red.

[image]

Comment: Hello, I was wondering how did you go from  v =(0.8784e4.88(−0.40),1)
to it = −1.681459915(0.123765,0.992312)
what steps happened ? 
would you be able to show more working out please ? 
thank you so much :D

Comment: Please. See included edit.

Comment: Hi I was more so confused on where the numbers (0.123765,0.992312) came from?
how did the vector: (0.8784e4.88(−0.40),1) turn into (0.123765,0.992312) ?
but the visual helped a lot too so thank you for that !

Comment: $\vec v = (\partial_x f,\partial_y f) = (0.8784e4.88(−0.40), 1) $ and $\|\vec v\| = \sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2}$.